# mongooose / mongodb streams vs array performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm seeing some unexpected performance numbers when it comes to sending a collection of documents from MongoDB using Mongoose, Express, and JSONStream when applicable.  I wanted to compare mongoose find vs. stream.  I had expected stream to be faster for larger document collections, but was surprised to see the toArray variants outperform them consistently.  I am thinking the wildcard might be my use of JSONStream to pipe the response to express.  My simple endpoints are below:

```
// run this after connecting to mongoose

var app = express();

var myModel = ...; // get mongoose model
var myCollection = myModel.collection;

// fetch 500 - use lean w/ mongoose
var queryOpts = { lean : true, limit : 500 };

// 35.958
app.get("/api/v1/stream", function(req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    myModel.find({ }, null, queryOpts)
    .stream().pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
});

// 36.228
app.get("/api/v1/mongostream", function(req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    myCollection.find({ }, queryOpts)
    .stream().pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
});

// 23.399ms
app.get("/api/v1/mongoarray", function(req, res) {
    myCollection.find({ }, queryOpts)
    .toArray(function(err, results) {
        res.json(results);
    });
});

// 23.908
app.get("/api/v1/array", function(req, res) {
    myModel.find({ }, null, queryOpts, function(err, results) {
        res.json(results);
    });
});

app.listen(4000);
```

The comment above each endpoint indicates the average request time reported by `ab -k -n 1000 <endpoint>`.  I am surprised that piping a cursor stream to JSONStream to the express response is around 50% slower than just fetching all at once and sending.  I had expected streaming the data to perform better.

Is there something I am doing that is obviously wrong?  Am I wrong to think that streams should be faster?  If JSONStream is the culprit, what is the best way to go from cursor stream to express response - if I buffer it all, wouldn't that be the same thing as one of the array variants?

Note the DB server is mongo 2.4.x and the mongo driver is 1.4.x.

**Update** I timed only the fetching / streaming portion and not the serialization aspect.  Both array variants and streaming were similar in times with a slight edge to the array variants (14.9ms vs. 15.3ms). Below are the endpoints:

```
// No serialization - just timing
// all are nearly the same - slight edge to
// arrays
app.get("/api/v2/stream", function(req, res) {
    var start = process.hrtime();
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    myModel.find({ }, null, queryOpts)
    .stream().on('end', function() {
        res.json(process.hrtime(start));
    });
});

app.get("/api/v2/mongostream", function(req, res) {
    var start = process.hrtime();
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    myCollection.find({ }, queryOpts)
    .stream().on('end', function() {
        res.json(process.hrtime(start));
    });
});

app.get("/api/v2/mongoarray", function(req, res) {
    var start = process.hrtime();
    myCollection.find({ }, queryOpts)
    .toArray(function(err, results) {
        res.json(process.hrtime(start));
    });
});

app.get("/api/v2/array", function(req, res) {
    var start = process.hrtime();
    myModel.find({ }, null, queryOpts, function(err, results) {
        res.json(process.hrtime(start));
    });
});
```

**Update 2** The output of `collection.stats()` and `collection.find({}).explain()` are below:

```
> db.myCollection.stats();
{
    "ns" : "myDb.myCollection",
    "count" : 1000,
    "size" : 419264,
    "avgObjSize" : 419.264,
    "storageSize" : 847872,
    "numExtents" : 4,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "lastExtentSize" : 655360,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 98112,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 40880,
        "_meta.tags_1" : 57232
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.myCollection.find({}).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1000,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1000,
    "nscanned" : 1000,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1000,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1000,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "server" : "LOCAL:27017"
}
```

Comment: So in either case, that's 1000 objects, or about 400K of data, which is sort of in the noise territory for Mongo. With 100 million objects in the collection, the cursor stream becomes interesting; with what you've got in there now, either query is going to be fast, likely indistinguishably so.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the output of db.mycollection.stats() and db.mycollection.find({}).explain() from the mongo shell.

Given the performance numbers you're seeing, it may be simply that for a large enough collection, a cold btree hit for a non-indexed query is where all the time goes, rather than to any overhead in Node per se.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I have updated the question with the output from those commands.  I figured Mongo would do the find really efficiently since I'm just asking for the first 500 documents it can find - no order or anything.